# How to run a command on startup for ubuntu server 18.04?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I want to run a command when I then start an EC2 instance. The AMI of the instance is `Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type`.

The following are the methods I've tried:

1. Create a script named `test.sh` under `/etc/init.d/`.
2. `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/test.sh`
3. `sudo chown root.root /etc/init.d/test.sh`
4. `sudo update-rc.d test.sh defaults`
5. Stop the EC2 instance.
6. Start the EC2 instance.

Here's the content of `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello > /home/ubuntu/test.log
```

I expected that I will see `test.log` file under `/home/ubuntu`. But I couldn't find the file.

I've also tried adding `echo hello > /home/ubuntu/test.log` to `/etc/rc.local` file. But it doesn't work, eighter.

Another method I've tried is Adding `echo hello > /home/ubuntu/test.log` to user data. This doesn't work, either.

[image]

I found a line saying 
`2019-05-13 03:23:18,162 - __init__.py[WARNING]: Unhandled non-multipart (text/x-not-multipart) userdata: 'b'echo hello > /home/ubunt'...'` in `/var/log/cloud-init.log`. But this is just a warning, not an error message.

What might be wrong with my configuration?

Are there any error logs left on the EC2?

Comment: you can use the instance user-data

Comment: Adding `echo hello > /home/ubuntu/test.log` to user data does not work.

Comment: Do you want to run on every boot, or first boot? Meaning, every time the instance starts, or only when it is created? User data is for first boot. If you want to run something on every boot, look into running custom scripts with systemd.

Comment: I want to run on every boot.

Comment: The [document](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) I provided in the answer is able to trigger the run on every boot by setting the `SCRIPTS-USER` parameter to `ALWAYS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed this [document](https://aws.amazon.com/tw/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/) to successfully run a command at startup.

I put the script inside the user data. Here's my user data:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo hello > /home/ubuntu/test.log
--//
```

`/bin/echo hello > /home/ubuntu/test.log` will be triggered on every boot. This is because `SCRIPTS-USER` is set to `ALWAYS`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to create an /etc/rc.local file.  Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't include one by default, but it will execute it if it exists (and is set with the execute bit/flag).  Some more information is available at https://vpsfix.com/community/server-administration/no-etc-rc-local-file-on-ubuntu-18-04-heres-what-to-do/